# Trigger event in Parent component from child component load in routing Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

In my Angular 2 application, I have app.module and app.component
app.component is my parent component and inside that, I have router-outlet to load pages based on my route.
based on an event in one of my components load based on the route I want to trigger event in my app component. Is it possible and if so how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

yep you have to trigger an output event emiter in an ngOnInit in your child componant.

so in your child component you'll have

```
@Output() myEventOnInit= new EventEmitter<dataType>();
ngOnInit() {
    myEventOnInit.emit(myData)
}
```

then in your app.component template:

```
<my-child-componant (myEventOnInit)="myFunctionThatHanddleTHeInitComponant($event)"></my-child-componant>
```

myFunctionThatHanddleTHeInitComponant is a function you'll have to describe in your parent componant.

I hope it helped you and that i've understood your issue.

Comment: your code snippet explain how child component trigger event on parent. what i am looking for is how to do it wen the child is loaded in route-outlet.

Comment: the ngOnInit()  function does that